# Want to add links to a method of another controller in the show screen using active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

in my active admin app i have 2 models, per example: Vehicle and Front.(Front has many Vehicles)

In the :show view of an Front, it lists all the vehicles that belong to it. And for each Vehicle it lists, it have a link "Remove" that removes the corresponding Vehicle from that Front. Here's what my code looks like:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Front do
    show do
      panel "Vehicles in this Front" do
        table_for(front.vehicles) do |vehicle|
          vehicle.column("id") {|vehicle| auto_link frente.vehicles}
          vehicle.column("category") {|vehicle| vehicle.descricao}
          vehicle.column("status") {|vehicle| vehicle.status}
          vehicle.column {link_to "Remove" , remove_admin_vehicle_path(vehicle.id), :method => :post}
        end
      end
```

And the Remove method from Vehicle:

```
member_action :remove , :method => :post do
  vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:id])
  vehicle.front = null
  vehicle.save!
  flash[:notice] = "vehicle removed"
  redirect_to :action => :show  
end
```

But when I click on the Remove link, theres an error: Its not sending the id from the vehicle. How can I send the id from the Vehicle?

Answer (score 0):

Use delete method and destroy action, it's right way.

so..
Try to use

```
vehicle.column {link_to "Remove" , remove_admin_vehicle_path(vehicle), :method => :post}
```

And show `rake routes` result.

Comment: I've tried this way, but it's still sending the Front id instead of the Vehicle id... the route is: /admin/vehicle/id/remove POST             
I think the problem is in the routes, but i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: hm, try to use `render text: params.inspect` for 1 line of your method. You will see where id and how you can take it.